# Is it possible to create reusable template in LESS?

Tags: css, function, less

Let's say I have two primary color "modes" in my application.

1. Dark mode / CSS:

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
  * {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

2. Light mode / CSS:

```
[data-theme="light"] {
  * {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Above CSS is working fine but any modification forces you to either copy-paste or to make redundant changes.

I would like to have some generic template.

```
.palette(@color1, @color2) {
  * {
    background-color: @color1,
    color: @color2,
  }
}
```

And use it later like this

```
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    .palette(@backgroundDark, @textDark)
  }

  [data-theme="light"] {
    .palette(@backgroundLight, @textLight)
  }
```

This way, I could reuse template and make edits in only one place. Is it something we can do with LESS?

Comment: See [(Parametric) Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixins-parametric-feature). Moreover your example code above is almost *exactly* the way how you'll write it.

Comment: Oh my gosh, right! I didn't notice parametric mixins in the docs. Thank you very much